# mysql stop working on xampp after all solutions it still doesnt work

Tags: mysql, xampp

logs:

```
2023-11-27 21:06:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231127 21:06:06
2023-11-27 21:06:06 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-11-27 21:06:06 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2023-11-27 21:06:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

i know of mysqlid and also the services to turn it off .
And still it doesnt work for me .
Another way to help please give.